# Interpretation of Goodman Diagram in Machine design

Tags: homework-and-exercises, material-science, stress-strain

[image]

In the Goodman diagram, the max and min stresses are plotted as a function of midrange stress. If I understand correctly, these are the upper and lower stress limits that can be applied in a repeated loading for infinite life. But the criteria for infinite life is that the endurance limit cannot be exceeded. How is it that if the midrange stress is greater than or less than 0 the Goodman diagram indicates that a material subjected to stresses greater than the endurance limit can still have an infinite life?

Comment: Sure, you can have steady stress over the endurance limit $\sigma = S_y > S_e$ and the part not fail. So the combination of alternating and steady stress  is what is indicated in the diagram above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. The reason is that endurance $S_e$ is tested in a uniaxial test machine with alternating stress (zero midrange stress). This defines points **B** and **B'** below. Also in static uniaxial stress test point **A** is defined with median stress = actual stress. Or with zero stress amplitude. So a constant load defines point **A** and the purely alternating loads (from - to + in equal amounts) defines **B** and **B'**.

[image: fig1]

The Goodman theory states that for all the in-between cases you draw lines from **A** to **B** and from **A** to **B'** to define the endurance limits in the presence of non-zero average stress (midrange stress).

This hypothesis is supported from testing (in some other page in Shigley book) and from the elastic theory of solids.

In looking at the diagram, the 45° line is the line of constant loading, and the breadth up and down is the amount of the oscillating load allowed. The "modified" endurance limit is the values $\sigma_a$ shown above which are $<S_e$ when $\sigma_m>0$. So to read this diagram you understand that **endurance decreases as steady loading increases**.